# Load local files to AWS stage in Snowflake using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, snowflake-connector

I am planning to ingest data from local system to snowflake table using the Amazon s3 internal stage. How can I load the data to the s3 stage using python ? Previously for loading the data to snowflake I was using snowflake's internal staging and using the below command to perform the operation.

```
put file://<local_file_location> @<creating_stage_snowflake> auto_compress=true
copy into <table_name> from @<creating_stage_snowflake>/<file_name>.gz file_format = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='~' error_on_column_count_mismatch=false, ENCODING = 'UTF-8')
```

What should be the approach to load the data from local system to amazon s3 and then copying these files from the staged table to the snowflake table using python.

Please share your inputs.

Comment: You can use [AWS Python SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) for that. You can't use Snowflake's Python connector for that.

Comment: @Sergiu I did check but didn't get any concrete solution. How to get the data to the Amazon S3 stage in snowflake ? Once I create stage based on the given command - 
  CREATE STAGE my_s3_stage
  STORAGE_INTEGRATION = s3_int
  URL = 's3://mybucket/encrypted_files/'
  FILE_FORMAT = my_csv_format;

How to ingest the data into this stage from the local system ? ( local system -> Amazon S3 stage)

Comment: If you created a stage with write access from Snowflake side, you can still use the PUT command to drop the files from local filesystem to that stage. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Snowsql tool with a command line, that refers to a small sql script that I created in my code. Its not very elegant, but it does the job. You can hide the connection info for snowsql in the .snowsql\config file.
This works well for individual programs, but is probably not the best solution for a multi process web service.